# Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() al pasarle un resultset

Tags: php, pdo, foreach

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\curso_php\pdo.php on line 9

Mi código es :

```
<?php 

try {
    $conexion = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=curso', 'root', '');
    echo "conexion exitosa";

    $resultado = $conexion->query ( 'SELECT * FROM curso');

    foreach ($resultado as $fila) {
        print_r($fila);
       }

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "¡Error!: " . $e->getMessage();
} >
```

Comment: En caso de no obtener datos de la tabla, el resultado devuelto por query es `false`. http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php#refsect1-pdo.query-returnvalues

Comment: los títulos deben ir acorde al problema que se te presenta por favor mejoralo

Answer (score 2):

$resultado es un "apuntador" al resultset obtenido con la consulta, para acceder a las filas deberas de hacerlo mediante las funciones fetch ej.

```
while($fila = $resultado->fetch()) {
        echo $row['nombreColumna'];// Y asi con cada columna
    }
```